# Attaching mouse click and mouseover events to a Bing maps pushpin not working

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I have multiple pins on the map each having two events associated with it (mouse click and mouse over). But only mouse over is firing but not the click. Below is the code I am using.

```
//Creating the pushpin
var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc);
    pin.Description = "Some address";

    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'mouseover', function(e){
         if (e.targetType == 'pushpin') {
         self.bingInfobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
         self.bingInfobox.setOptions({
             visible: true, title: e.target.Title, description:  e.target.Description });
           }       
    });

    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', function(e){
         if (e.targetType == 'pushpin') {

           // some functionality..
         }   
    });
```

Please suggest..

Comment: Does self.bingInfobox refer to the built-in infobox of Bing Maps or is it a custom implementation you added?

Comment: Yes, self.bingInfobox refer to built-in infobox only..

Answer (score 0):

4 years... Shameful no one has answered.

Essentially, the mouseover event is firing, and your infobox is popping up. It's probably popping up *over* the pin.

So, when you click, you're clicking on the infobox and not on the pin itself, so no pin click event firing.

Variety of options to choose from to fix the issue depending on what is happening on your map:

Ensure the pin layer z-index is higher than the infobox layer (of course, then the info box could end up being partially hidden behind other pins in the layer).

Add an offset to the infobox options to shift it off the pin.

Customise your infobox so that you have control of what it looks like and where it's positioned - ensuring the pin is visible to the clicking.

Other options I'm sure. At the very least, however, overlaying is most likely the source of the problem.